# Google Map not loading properly in AngularJs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I followed this simple sample from [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) and converted to a simple angular directive.

**mc-maps.directive.js**

```
...

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        center: '=center',
    },
    templateUrl: 'app/directives/mc-maps/mc-maps.html',
    link: link,
};

function link(scope, element, attrs){

    var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0].querySelector('#map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: scope.center
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: scope.center,
        map: map
    });
}

...
```

**mc-maps.html**

```
<div id="map" style="height:400px; width:100%;"></div>
```

**view.html**

```
<h3>Location</h3>
<div>
    <mc-maps center="{lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}"></mc-maps>
</div>
```

Im thinking maybe it has something to do with the loading of the DOM. But Im not sure. Here's what's showing (see image below).

[image]

Sometimes the marker shows on the far right corner, but disappears after a very short period.

Thanks for helping.

**P.S.**

Sometimes the map loads, when I came from another `ui-router` state, but it doesnt load when I just refresh the page directly in the maps `ui-router` state.

**UPDATE**

Added the whole **view.html**

Comment: could you add the HTML where you load both your Angular scripts and the Google maps library ?

Comment: (and where is the variable `uluru` coming from ?)

Comment: +1 to the actual page. Did you add an APi key? also - look into the developer console - i am sure it will have some useful error messages.

Comment: @ValLeNain @kaskedar The `view.html` is just a standard `ui-router` view. But I updated it. And yes the API keys are present.

Comment: @ValLeNain `uluru` was from the docu, I just forgot to replace is with `scope.center`

Comment: @kaskader Actually there was no error coming from the google map library or anything related to the map directive.

Comment: you also have to define the `zoom` property of the map (it is a required field).